# Can mod_security be configured to create log only?

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-security

I've installed mod_security on openSUSE and want to make it log only.

I want absolutely no blocking or filtering of any kind.

I've created a config file as:

```
SecAuditEngine On
SecAuditLog /siteA/user/logs/mod.log
SecAuditLogParts ABIZ
```

This is logging, but I've noticed some pages elements, CSS/JS etc, are being blocked.

How do I set this for logging only ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you find my answer useful?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is `SecRuleEngine DetectionOnly`.

Edit your `/etc/modsecurity/modesecurity.conf` accordingly then restart your web server.